# DevExpress Grid App (DXTREME) - How to bind to the ItemNavigationTargetType?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-8, devexpress

I am working on my first windows 8 application using the devexpress grid app template provided in the New Wizard. Everything is working out fine but however, I would like to bind the `MenuItems` to specific pages instead of using the `ItemsDetailPage` for all my menuitems. I have managed to figure out that I need to change the following to the page I want to use:

`ItemNavigationTargetType="ItemsDetailPage"` to `ItemNavigationTargetType="MyPage"`

This works fine. I have created another parameter for my menu item which is a "string TargetType". This I use to specify the page the menu item should open. Then I would like to bind this property to the above code to look like the following:

```
ItemNavigationTargetType="{Binding TargetType}"
```

But this will not work. Is there another way I can do this. Please assist?

Comment: Why do you open this Question multiple times on several sites? http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q457245 , that's not nice.... and "But this will not work" is not a really good description, what is not working ? is there any error or anything?

Comment: Hi Mark, my apologises for this, but I think stackoverflow provides a quickier response to questions. To elaborate on what is not working, the binding to the MenuItem Property "TargetType" I have created returns the correct Page that is bound to a menu item but however when I click on the MenuItem on my GroupItemsPage it does not do anything. Since I have given the ItemNavigationTargetType property the correct Page to link to, I would expect it to open that page. Please assist. Next time I will just post on Stackoverflow.

Comment: And besides I only posted on the devexpress site and stackoverflow, seeing that the issue I am trying to resolve is a Devexpress issue posted as a ticket. The main reason I would like to post on Stackoverflow is that it is more exposed to more developers that may have done something similar and hence more chances of my problem being resolved.

Comment: so every of your items in the Grid has a TargetType Property? then your binding is not correct if you want to bind it to a specific item try to bind the SelectedItem ItemNavigationTargetType="{Binding ElementName=YourGrid,Path=SelectedItem.TargetType}", somethign like that can't logon my windows 8 atm to test it. but that should give you the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DXGridView.ItemNavigationTargetTypeBinding](http://help.devexpress.com/#XAML/DevExpressUIXamlLayoutDXGridView_ItemNavigationTargetTypeBindingtopic) property to specify the name of the Page class to be opened when an end-user clicks a [DXGridView](http://help.devexpress.com/#XAML/clsDevExpressUIXamlLayoutDXGridViewtopic) item.

P.S. I believe the best way to get **guaranteed assistance** with any DevExpress controls is contacting with [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).